# How to make ClickableSpan links in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder clickable?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components, spannablestringbuilder, clickablespan

I have a `SpannableStringBuilder` object with a `ClickableSpan` link like this,

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hi StackOverflow!");

ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

ssb.setSpan(clickableSpan, 3, 16, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

This works fine when I set it to a `TextView` and after using `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())`

When I set the `ssb` object to the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`,

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setTitle("My Dialog")
                .setMessage(ssb)
                .show();
```

It displays as a clickable link but cannot actually click it
[image: MaterialAlertDialogBuilder preview]
I couldn't find a way to use `setMovementMethod` for the message in `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`. Is there any way to make it clickable?

Comment: Create a custom view, put a textView within that view, apply setMovementMethod to that textView and then set that custom view to your material alert dialog.

Comment: @Bhavnik yes I have tried that and it works, but the problem of using a custom view is it will look different than the MaterialAlertDialogBuilder's message, which defeat the purpose of using it in the first place. I would like to keep the appearance of MaterialAlertDialogBuilder's message view.

Comment: Well in that you can use Linkify class to make your string content clickable.

Comment: @Amila To apply to your `TextView` the same style just use in your TextView the  `style="?attr/materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle"` or `style="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is code snippet to make your spannable content clickable, give it a try.

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(msg); // Here msg should have url to enable clicking
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
```

After that put your alertdialog code here

```
//Alert dialog code
```

Then get id of textview of your MaterialAlertDialog, below line of code must be called after dialog.show() like this,

```
((TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message))
.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thank you! .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) part helped me.

Comment: That sounds cool, Happy coding @Mike.

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering how to add a hyperlink to a `MaterialAlertDialog` message via a static string that contains ***simple*** html tags without having to create a custom view (e.g. `Hello <a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program'> World </a>`), [@Bhavnik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983405/2414033) answer helped a lot:

```kotlin
val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title))
                    .setMessage(getText(R.string.dialog_content))
                    ...
                    .show()    //must after show()!!
dialog.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.message)?.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

The main trick is indeed to add the `LinkMovementMethod` after showing the dialog, but also don't forget to get the string with `getText` in order to keep the styling.

For more complex html, `.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getText(R.string.dialog_content).toString(), flags))` also seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Just define a `TextView` with the default style  (**`@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text`**) provided by the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textview1"
  style="?attr/materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle"
  ...>
```

Then set the `SpannableStringBuilder` as text:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb =....
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_text_view, null);
TextView customTextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
customTextView.setText(ssb);
customTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Finally:

```
 MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
        .setTitle("My Dialog")
        .setView(dialogView)
        ...
```